# Android Loader used with SimpleCursorAdapter and ContentProvider not updating

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-listfragment, loader

I have a list fragment which loads data from a ContentProvider using a Loader and SimpleCursorAdapter. I think that I have followed correctly the directions given by google examples, but my ListView is not updated when underlying data changes. This is what I'm doing:

**ContentProvider**

```
@Override
public synchronized Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    ...
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);

    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}
```

**ListFragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] dbColumns = new String[] { CheckpointsView.COL_TYPE, CheckpointsView.COL_DESCRIPTION };
    int[] listColumnIds = new int[] { R.id.lci_img_icon, R.id.lci_txt_description };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_checkpoints_item, null, dbColumns, listColumnIds, 0);
    ...
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
        getActivity(),
        CheckpointsView.CONTENT_URI,
        CheckpointsView.LOADER_PROJECTION,
        whereClause,
        null,
        null
    );
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

At some point of the code that I know that data was just added, I trie calling
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`,
but it didn't work either.

The only way to make the list refresh is either by exiting the activity and relaunching it, or by recreating the loader manually by writing

```
getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, GreenScanFragment.this);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid! After spending so much time, I had to post a question in order to find the answer myself. The problem is solved if I call `context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(CheckpointsView.CONTENT_URI, null, false);` where I am updating the data.